# Getting resource instead of number as a result of count(column_name)

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to get the number of columns from a table :

```
$query = "select count(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name = '".$tableName."'";
$columns = pg_query($query);
echo $columns;
```

but instead of number I get a mysterious `Resource id #61`.
Converting to other types like `string` or `int` doesn't help.

Comment: Ever checked what pg_query() returns?

Comment: The syntax is `$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors");` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- First argument is optional, so your comment gives nothing in that case.

Comment: as per manual pg_query() returns resource on success ...

Comment: @ElonThan: it's optional, true, but it's worth using, as I explained (or rather, touched on) in my answer

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem On bigger projects you will use something better to manage connections, but true, it can only help if you pass connection there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_query` returns a resource to the query result, to get the actual rows, you can use any of the `pg_fetch_*` functions, such as [`pg_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php)

All this is well documented [on php.net/pg_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php). Look at the functions' signature:

```
resource pg_query ([ resource $connection ], string $query )
//return type function name (params)
```

Hence, what you need is:

```
$result = pg_query($query);
$columns = pg_fetch_all($result);
var_dump($columns);
```

Also, please get into the habit of passing the connection resource to the `pg_query` call explicitly... there's no telling what connection you're using, when working on a sizeable project, with multiple connections.

Answer (score 1):

`pg_query()` returns resource and it's correct behaviour. You can check it in manual (what you definitely should do anyway).

To get rows from that resource you can use functions like `pg_fetch_all()` or `pg_fetch_row()`. Read about both and decide which one will be better in that case.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM '".$tableName."' ";
$result= pg_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}
$i = 1;
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "Column[$i] names: ".$row[0]."";
  echo "<br />";
  $i++;
}

echo "Column Count: ".$i;
```